# Java concurrency: some assistance

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class like this:

```
package crossRoadConcurency;

import java.util.List;

public class TourGuide 
{
    private volatile boolean isGuiding;
    private volatile boolean isInShop;
    private final Object lockObject = new Object();
    private final int id;

    public TourGuide(int id)
    {
        this.isGuiding=false;
        this.isInShop=false;
        this.id=id;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isFree()
    {
        return !isGuiding && !isInShop;
    }

    public void guide(final Tourist[] tourists)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            synchronized (lockObject) 
            {
                while(!isFree()) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Guide "+id+" is bussy. Waiting... ");
                        lockObject.wait();
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            isGuiding=true;
            System.out.println("Guide "+id+" is guiding "+tourists.length+" tourists");
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(4000);//lets not wait one hour, shall we?
                for (Tourist tourist : tourists) 
                {
                    tourist.exit();
                }
                System.out.println("All tourists exited for guide "+id+". Going to shop");
                isInShop=true;
                isGuiding=false;//if we invert the way we give these values bad thing may happen
                Thread.sleep(4000);
                isInShop=false;
                System.out.println("Guide "+id+" is free");
                synchronized (lockObject) 
                {
                    lockObject.notifyAll();
                }
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

        }
    }).start();
}
}
```

And another class:

```
package crossRoadConcurency;

import java.util.Random;

public class Tourist 
{
    public void exit() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));// max one second to exit
    }
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
package crossRoadConcurency;

import java.util.List;

public class Main 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Tourist[] tourists = new Tourist[20];
        for (int i=0;i<tourists.length;i++) 
        {
            tourists[i]=new Tourist();
        }
        TourGuide guide = new TourGuide(0);
        guide.guide(tourists);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        guide.guide(tourists);

    }

}
```

The problem is I get this output:

```
Guide 0 is guiding 20 tourists
All tourists exited for guide 0. Going to shop
Guide 0 is free
Exception in thread "Thread-0" Guide 0 is guiding 20 tourists
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at crossRoadConcurency.TourGide$1.run(TourGide.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
All tourists exited for guide 0. Going to shop
Guide 0 is free
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at crossRoadConcurency.TourGide$1.run(TourGide.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

<del>**First question**: Why am I not seeing the "waiting output"</del>
<del>**Second question**: Why am I getting an exception</del>
**Third question**: Is there a better way to do this, because I am fairly certain this concept is mixed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't see "wait" because your guide is free by default. `!isGuide && !isInShop` returns true while you only print when `!isFree()`.
2. You should call `lockObject.notifyAll()`. A direct call to `notifyAll()` by default invoke on this object and you certainly didn't hold the monitor of the anoymous object implementing Runnable interface because you never did by calling `synchroized(this)`. That's why you got the exception.
3. Yes. You should use an `Executor` e.g. `SingleThreadExecutor` together with a concurrent queue. That's the robust and easy way to implement concurrency unless you goes on high performance computing. That package also provide excellent functinoalities and supporting utilitiy classes. Check out `java.util.concurrent`.

BTW, your package name contains Upper letter which isn't recommended by java programming specification.

Comment: 1. By default he is, but see the main method - I have 2 calls to the guide method, where the second should catch the guide in busy mode.
2. See the edited question. I still get the exception

Comment: You started 2 threads but you could well have both thread checking this flag first before any thread set them to true.

Comment: @user3580294 but that's not useful since he start another thread inside the method and run off it. Where inside that thread he depends on the lockObject. Your synchronized on the method only cause the thread creation and starting being synchronized.

Comment: @MarioStoilov I'm actually not getting any exceptions when running your code right now...

Comment: @AlexSuo You're right, I was mixing up the unsynchronized `run()` method with the synchronized `guide()` method. My mistake.

Comment: @user3580294 yes, there are no exceptions now, but I want to see the "waiting" output

Comment: @MarioStoilov Wouldn't you need to at least create multiple threads for that? You only have one `TourGuide`...

Comment: @user3580294 which his guide method creates a new thread every time it's called

Comment: @MarioStoilov True. Could be due to the fact that only a single thread could lock `lockObject` at any point. You set `isGuiding` and `isInShop` to a state such that the `while` loop will never be entered.

Comment: @user3580294 yeah, kinda noticed that. See the final edit. Thank you and Alex Suo

Comment: @MarioStoilov Minor quibble - I'd put `isGuiding = true;` *inside* the first `synchronized` block. That way, the second thread is guaranteed to see the change to the variable. Otherwise it's entirely possible that a locally cached version of `isGuiding` for the second thread won't be updated.

Answer (score -1):

when we synchronize any block or method, we should synchronize on class lock or object lock.

but here you have locked on some object which is no where related to caller of that method

so change this from  `synchronized (lockObject)` to like below and run

```
synchronized (this)
```

Comment: If you look OP's calling `wait()` and `notifyAll()` on `lockObject`, so I believe the `synchronized` block is correct

Comment: ha i am getting output like below after putting synchronized(this) Guide 0 is bussy. Waiting... 
Guide 0 is guiding 20 tourists
All tourists exited for guide 0. Going to shop
Guide 0 is free

Comment: ...I actually get no exceptions with OP's code as is... So perhaps it's not that section that's throwing things off.